# Objective-C Base Class Property Custom Getter Not Being Called From Subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, properties, getter

Base Class Interface:

```
@interface Base : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=getPriceForListing) double_t priceForListing;

@end
```

Base Class Implementation:

```
@implementation Base

-(double_t)getPriceForListing
{
    if (self.listPriceLow > 0 && self.listPriceHigh > 0)
    {
        return self.listPriceLow;
    }
    else if (self.listPriceLow > 0)
    {
        return self.listPriceLow;
    }
    else if (self.listPriceHigh > 0)
    {
        return self.listPriceHigh;
    }
    else
    {
        return self.currentPrice;
    }
}

@end
```

Subclass Interface:

```
@interface Subclass : Base

@end
```

Subclass Implementation:

```
@implementation Subclass

@dynamic priceForListing;

@end
```

How subclass is used:

```
Subclass *sub = [[Subclass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", sub.priceForListing);
```

The problem I am having here is that `sub.priceForListing` always returns zero and the base class getter is never being called, at least no breakpoint is being hit in there.

Comment: Delete: @dynamic priceForListing;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined the "getter" as `getPriceForListing` but are trying to access it with `priceForListing`. Just omit the custom name.

Rename the "getter" method to `priceForListing`.

If there is no backing instance variable, IOW it is never set you can specify it to be `readonly`.

As mentioned in the comments: Delete: `@dynamic priceForListing;`.

FYI: In Objective-C/Cocoa  the "get" prefix is reserved by convention for methods that return a value by reference. Getters do not have a "get" prefix.

Comment: Also, there's no need for the @dynamic declaration here. That only confuses things further (and is probably masking a warning).

Comment: Good catch on the potentially missing warning!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for clearing this up.  I totally missed the renamed getter.